# IMAP email migration from Apptix to Office 365

Tags: exchange, imap, microsoft-office-365

I am having issues setting up a migration from Apptix to Office 365 of 41 users in my company.

I've found a couple guides on the Microsoft website about how to do it (Thank you Google) but I keep coming up with problems. I am trying to set up a mailbox migration through IMAP to get all of my users' emails over to Office 365 before we make the transition over from Apptix.

One of the forums suggested using IMAP, since a CSV file can be uploaded to Office 365 and it will check for incoming mail for each user every 24 hours. My problem is that when I do this, I just get errors.

The link I got was this: http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/ms.exch.ecp.emailmigrationstatuslearnmore.aspx#imap

I was wondering if anyone has successfully managed this transition. I'm using imap.apptixemail.net as the IMAP server (FQDN)

Thank you for the help in advance. Any help or push in the right direction would be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct FQDN is imap.collaborationhost.net for my version of Exchange.

Solved it!